# Calculation of Rise in Height of water in a Frustum of Right Circular Cone

Tags: geometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

A volume of frustum of right circular cone is calculated as follows. With known h, R & r of a container with the shape shown below, how to find out the rise in height for each time $7m^3$ of water is added in the container? Suppose there is no water in the container initially.

[image]

r is the radius at the topmost level.
The rise in height of water should be different for each time. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please give some context for your question.

Comment: You need to take slices and integrate.

Comment: In fact, it is considering a real situation, but not a question from text book.  
I want to calculate the rise in height of concrete for each load added in the pile shaft. https://na.cx/i/U3XKd3.gif
Each load of concrete is 7m3. 
I am not good at maths....Hope can work out for me.... 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS: At any instant, the radius $R_x$ at a vertical height $x$ from the  bottom is given as $$R_x=R-\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)x$$
Now, consider an elementary slice of thickness $dx$ & radius $R_x$ at a a normal height $x$ from the bottom of frustum. 
Te volume of elementary slice $$dV=\pi R_x^2\ dx=\pi \left(R-\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)x\right)^2\ dx$$ 
Now, let the rise be $x_1$ in  first time to fill $7\ m^3$ of water then using integration with proper limits 
$$\int_0^7\ dV=\int_0^{x_1}\pi \left(R-\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)x\right)^2\ dx$$ 
$$7=\frac{\pi h}{3(R-r)}\left(\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)^3x_1^3-3R\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)^2x_1^2+3R^2\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)x_1\right)$$
  $$\frac\pi 3\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)^3x_1^3-\pi R\left(\frac{R-r}{h}\right)x_1^2+\pi R^2 x_1-7=0$$
Each time, one need to solve cubic equation, as obtained above,  to find rises in height $x_1, x_2, ....$